# Mirth Connect Administrator Won't Launch

Tags: java, mirth, mirth-connect

I have Mirth Connect Version 3.5.0.8232 installed on a VM with Window 7 Ultimate N and Java 1.8 build 131. I've been able to start Mirth Connect server successfully; however, I am not able to launch the Administrator tool. When I clicked on the administrator button, It opened the window saying starting application, but it closed it and the administrator window never open.  So far, I restarted the service, rebooted the computer, reinstalled Mirth, cleared java cache (several times) successfully. The log file had no error. I was able to login via https//:localhost:8443; however, I tried launching the administrative tool by clicking on Admin and Launch Administrator on the upper right corner. It did not open the administrator tool, but it did download a file call webstart.jnlp. Double click on the file did not do anything. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

This is the log file:

```
INFO  2017-05-05 08:10:05,626 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: Mirth Connect 3.5.0.8232 (Built on April 18, 2017) server successfully started.
INFO  2017-05-05 08:10:05,629 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: This product was developed by Mirth Corporation (http://www.mirthcorp.com) and its contributors (c)2005-2017.
INFO  2017-05-05 08:10:05,629 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: Running Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_131 on Windows 7 (6.1, amd64), sqlserver, with charset windows-1252.
INFO  2017-05-05 08:10:05,633 [Main Server Thread] com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth: Web server running at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/ and https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8443/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the latest version of java and mirth connect. I installed an earlier version of java. 1.8 update 60 since I had a copy already save on my local. I reinstalled the latest version of Mirth Connect. Everything appears to be  working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Java wanted to upgrade but that was happening behind the scene. Since I don't want to upgrade JRE that I have for certain reasons, what I did is saved *webstart.jnlp* and running it manually with *javaws*, i.e.:

```
javaws webstart.jnlp
```

Answer (score 0):

Java wanted to update itself in the foreground but got stuck. Once I updated Java to the latest version it worked. Mirth 3.8.0.